# Spring MVC Controller recieves Calendar in wrong UTC offset

Tags: java, spring, date, model-view-controller, calendar

I'm a bit confused with how Spring MVC handles dates.

I made a controller that recieves a Calendar object.

```
@RequestParam(value = "startdate", required = false) 
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ") Calendar startDate
```

Then I wrote a unit test that sends the following date **2012-01-10T11:00:00.000+00:00** however when I then look at what arrives at the server side and I call

```
int i = startDate.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```

I end up with i = 12, instead of the expected 11.  Is this normal behaviour ?  Also if it is what am I missing and whats the best way to actually get it to 11:00:00 ? It might help to mention that I'm currently in timezone UTC+1 and the server runs localy on my machine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe to have found the answer.  It seemingly has something to do with they timezone the JVM is running in.  I basicly added this to my startup method

```
    System.setProperty("user.timezone", "UTC");
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

This fixed the behavior , although I'm hoping I didn't break anything else in the application running with dates.  The unit tests are still green but lets hope that there are not false positives amoungst them

Comment: This changed the whole time zone in JVM. sometimes only need utc timezone on spring mvc param.